# Can I configure JTidy to ignore certain errors and warnings?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jtidy

I am using JTidy to validate snippets of HTML generated in Java a rendering class. I would like to ignore certain warnings <strike>and errors</strike>.

(EDIT: On second thoughts I might not want to suppress **errors**)

For example, the following snippet that is generated:

```
<img src='/images/icon.gif'>
```

results in this warning:

`line 5 column 7 - Warning: img lacks "alt" attribute`

Can I configure JTidy to ignore specific checks such as this one?

The method I use to check is:

```
public static boolean isValidHtml(String htmlSnippet) {
    String untestedHtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><HTML>" +
            "<head><title>Wrapper HTML For Testing</title></head>" +
            htmlSnippet +
            "</HTML>";

    final Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    final Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(writer, true));

    tidy.parseDOM(new StringReader(untestedHtml), writer);

    if (tidy.getParseErrors() > 0 || tidy.getParseWarnings() > 0) {
        System.err.println(writer);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [configuration class](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/Configuration.html) to do this:

```
  Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
  tidy.setShowErrors(0);
  tidy.setForceOutput(true);
```